# Unable to find an element with a testID

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm building a React Native app. Within my `GigsByDay` component, there is a TouchableOpacity element which, when pressed, directs the user to a `GigDetails` screen. I'm trying to test this particular functionality using Jest and React Native Testing Library.

I've written the following test, but have received the error:

> Unable to find an element with testID: gigs-today-card

The test is as follows:

```
describe("gigs by week component", () => {
  let navigation;

  beforeEach(() => {
    navigation = { navigate: jest.fn() };
  });

  test("that when gig listing is pressed on it redirects user to Gig Details page", () => {
    render(<GigsByDay navigation={navigation} />);
    const gigCard = screen.getByTestId("gigs-today-card");
    fireEvent.press(gigCard);
    expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("GigDetails");
  });
});
```

The element it's testing is as follows:

```
      <TouchableOpacity
        testID="gigs-today-card"
        style={styles.gigCard}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('GigDetails', {
            venue: item.venue,
            gigName: item.gigName,
            blurb: item.blurb,
            isFree: item.isFree,
            image: item.image,
            genre: item.genre,
            dateAndTime: {...item.dateAndTime},
            tickets: item.tickets,
            id:item.id
          })
        }>
        <View style={styles.gigCard_items}>
          <Image
            style={styles.gigCard_items_img}
            source={require('../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png')}
          />
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.gigCard_header}>{item.gigName}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.gigCard_details}>{item.venue}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

I've tried fixing my test as follows, but to no success:

```
  test("that when gig listing is pressed on it redirects user to Gig Details page", async () => {
    render(<GigsByDay navigation={navigation} />);
    await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByTestId('gigs-today-card')).toBeTruthy()
})
    const gigCard = screen.getByTestId("gigs-today-card");
    fireEvent.press(gigCard);
    expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("GigDetails");
  });
});
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I also tried assigning the `testID` to the view within the TouchableOpacity element.

For context, here's the whole `GigsByDay` component:

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { FlatList,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet,View,Image,Text } from 'react-native'
import { listProps } from '../routes/homeStack';
import { GigObject } from '../routes/homeStack';

type ListScreenNavigationProp = listProps['navigation']

interface Props {
  gigsFromSelectedDate: GigObject[],
  navigation: ListScreenNavigationProp
}

const GigsByDay:FC<Props> = ({ gigsFromSelectedDate, navigation }):JSX.Element => (
  <FlatList
    testID='gigs-today'
    data={gigsFromSelectedDate}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        testID="gigs-today-card"
        style={styles.gigCard}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('GigDetails', {
            venue: item.venue,
            gigName: item.gigName,
            blurb: item.blurb,
            isFree: item.isFree,
            image: item.image,
            genre: item.genre,
            dateAndTime: {...item.dateAndTime},
            tickets: item.tickets,
            id:item.id
          })
        }>
        <View style={styles.gigCard_items}>
          <Image
            style={styles.gigCard_items_img}
            source={require('../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png')}
          />
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.gigCard_header}>{item.gigName}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.gigCard_details}>{item.venue}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pass the `gigsFromSelectedDate` prop with some mock array data so that the flat list would render its elements based on the array length. Currently, you are not passing it. Please check the code below.

```
  test('that when gig listing is pressed on it redirects user to Gig Details page', () => {
    const mockData = [{venue: 'some venue', 
                      gigName: 'some gigName, 
                      blurb: 'some blurb',
                      isFree: 'some isFree', 
                      image: 'some image', 
                      genre: 'some genre', 
                      dateAndTime: {}, 
                      tickets: ['some ticket'],
                     id: 'some id'}]
    const screen = render(<GigsByDay navigation={navigation} gigsFromSelectedDate={mockData} />);
    const gigCard = screen.getByTestId('gigs-today-card');
    fireEvent.press(gigCard);
    expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('GigDetails');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed below package?
please check your Package.json

"@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.1"

if not please install it
then import it where you have written test cases.

import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';

if it is already present in then try below properties of jest-native.

const gigCard = screen.queryByTestId("gigs-today-card");

const gigCard = screen.findByTestId("gigs-today-card");